# ArgoCD CLI login with server running with --insecure

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, argocd

So I have installed ArgoCD on to my cluster. I then patched it with,

```
kubectl -n argocd patch deployment argocd-server --type json -p='[ { "op": "replace", "path":"/spec/template/spec/containers/0/command","value": ["argocd-server","--insecure"] }]'
```

so that i can host it with Contour dealing with the TLS / SSL Cert. Heres the config for the ingress / Contour:

```
apiVersion: projectcontour.io/v1
kind: HTTPProxy
metadata:
  name: argocd
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  virtualhost:
    fqdn: argo.xxx.com
    tls:
      secretName: default/cert
  routes:
    - requestHeadersPolicy:
        set:
        - name: l5d-dst-override
          value: argocd-server.argocd.svc.cluster.local:443
      services:
        - name: argocd-server
          port: 443
      conditions:
      - prefix: /
      loadBalancerPolicy:
        strategy: Cookie
```

But now cant login to the Argo server with the cli, even using port-forward (which worked, before i patched the server with the 'insecure' flag).

When trying to use the port-forward access, i get this

```
error creating error stream for port 8080 -> 8080: EOF
```

Using,

```
kubectl port-forward svc/argocd-server -n argocd 8080:443
```

So I have tried as many options / flags as i can think of to login via the ingress / contour url,

```
argocd login argo.xxx.com --plaintext --insecure --grpc-web

argocd login argo.xxx.com --plaintext --insecure

argocd login argo.xxx.com --plaintext

argocd login argo.xxx.com --insecure --grpc-web
```

I either get back a 404 or a 502. Sometimes an empty error code,

```
FATA[0007] rpc error: code = Unavailable desc =   

FATA[0003] rpc error: code = Unknown desc = POST http://argo.xxx.com:443/session.SessionService/Create failed with status code 502 

FATA[0002] rpc error: code = Unknown desc = POST https://argo.xxx.com:443/argocd/session.SessionService/Create failed with status code 404
```

With out any flags added to login, this is the error i get back,

```
FATA[0007] rpc error: code = Internal desc = transport: received the unexpected content-type "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
```

Answer (score 0):

It might have been a while, and could have been solved, but I had a similar issue.

With the ArgoCD version `2.4.14` I was able to resolve the issue using the command:

```
argocd login --insecure --port-forward --port-forward-namespace=argocd --plaintext
Username: admin
Password:
'admin:login' logged in successfully
Context 'port-forward' updated
```

I allowed the CLI to use its selector `app.kubernetes.io/name=argocd-server` to find the service in the `argocd` namespace.